# Captcha ocr solver

Tags: python, ocr, captcha

I am trying the captcha_ocr example from colab to solve my captchas.
here is the code I am trying https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/captcha_ocr.ipynb#scrollTo=8v3O0Ai2rXV-

and here are the images I have: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dpm9dA9ucguW4ab2U6QUCOsSZcUWNNri/view?usp=sharing

I make the batch_size =1, img_width= 80 and img_height = 35. the code works, I am training the NN but when i predict the results are terrible, not even one of the letters is predicted correctly. any pointers for improvment?